# How to create bootable floppy disk images (.img)

Tags: windows-7, images, floppy

I am thinking of creating my own OS. I downloaded bochs for a test machine, and now I need a 'floppy' to boot from (it boots from .img files). I need a way to create bootable disk images. I have neither physical floppies or a floppy drive. My requirements are:

I need a way to create a bootable disk image.

I need a way to manipulate files on the 'disk'.

The best solution I found was VFD, but I have Windows 7 64-bit, and VFD is explicitly designed to work only on 32-bit hardware. I searched high and low on Google and I couldn't find anything both free and useful.

Is there a 64 bit solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [**UltraISO**](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/).  While it is not free, IIRC, the limits improsed on the trial version still allows making floppy images.

Comment: I'll delete this answer if my memory is wrong.  Also, I may be getting confused with PowerISO.  I have used both in the past, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: Is it a limited-time trial? I couldn't find any info on the trial version. I do have a blank, unformatted floppy image created by bochs.

Comment: @kendfrey: IIRC, it is a feature-limited trial and not time-limited, where you can only make images of up to a certain (small) size.

Comment: OK, thanks, I got a formatted bootable floppy disk image.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to read user manuals.  Chapter 8 of the user manual for Bochs points one to [the Bochs WWW site](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/links.html) where one can find listed two Win32 ports of MTOOLS, for starters.